# Cocoa: iTunes and XCode 4 style LCD displays

Tags: cocoa, element, lcdui

Where can I find a UI element of code on the internet to implement an LCD like display as in XCode 4 and iTunes.

The one in XCode 4 is a bit more advanced than the iTunes ones, it offers more functionality.

Is this a standard element, or is it a private Apple one?

Comment: It's custom. You'll need to make one yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a private Apple one. I built one for myself using a graphics program for the background and the interface builder to design the control.

I used [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/) as the graphics program and let it create the Core Graphics implementation for the background. That way I can even change the color of the background and it's easily resizable.